# Рассылка по базе email из MySQL на PHP7 с Redbeanphp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, redbeanphp

**Нужно реализовать рассылку новостей зарегистрированным пользователям сайта.**

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что ни на форумах ни в YouTube - ну прям нигде нет формы рассылки писем по базе email из MySQL - на **PHP7** - где для подключения к БД используется Redbeanphp.

Если более развернуто - то mysql_query и т.д. в PHP7 не работают.
При попытки использовать в стандартной форме (что работала на PHP5) - mysqli_query - выходит очень много ошибок - аж страшно разбирать.

Если есть у кого рабочая форма на PHP7 с RedBeanPHP - буду признателен.
Или просто форма, что заработает на PHP7 - где все emails - массивом находятся в переменной $usermail (То есть без конекта к БД и т.п.)

Comment: Замените mysql_* на PDO и php перестанет ругаться.

Comment: либо используйте mysqli_query https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: а что значит "рабочая форма на PHP7 с RedBeanPHP "? что конкретно не получается? Если вы используете библиотеку redbean, зачем вам mysql_query?

Comment: Тогда и  делайте все CRUD операции с помощью библиотеки https://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/crud

Comment: @МаксМаксимус весь CRUD и делается через неё. 
Мне нужно реализовать функционал рассылки новостей зарегистрированным пользователям. Все примеры, что есть - на php5, но не на php7.

Comment: возможно вам смогут помочь, если вы приведете конкретный код с описанием проблемы